# rules php condition not working

Tags: rules, userpoints

I have been trying to use the following php condition to achieve a specific rule required for my project, but I keep failing to match the condition, please help.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `mid` FROM `managed_staff_points` WHERE `uid` = '[userpoints-transaction:user:uid]'  ";
$result = db_query($sql);
if ($result == '[site:current-user:uid]') {
    return TRUE;
else
    return FALSE;
}
?>
```